# I have a 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function ' and i dont understand why?

Tags: javascript

```
    function initImages(paths){
        game.requiredImages = paths.length;
        for(i in paths)
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = paths[i];
            game.images[i] = img;
            game.images[i].onload = function(){
                game.doneImages++;
            }
        }
    }

    function checkImages(){
        if(game.doneImages >= game.requiredImages){
            init();
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                checkImages();
            }, 1);      
        }   
    }
    initImages(["player.png", "enemy.png", "bullet.png"]);
    checkImages();
});
```

})();

There is a problem on line 78=> function initImages(paths){
I have not a clue as to whats wrong, i have been following a tutorial and copied the code exact; any help would be great

Comment: You seem to be missing part of the code, which also is not all correctly formatted.

Comment: The error suggests that a `function` keyword wasn't expected *after* something else. So, what's before `function initImages`? Also, you might try a linter like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a { after `for(i in paths)` which is causing your closures to end prematurely.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats fixed it! Much love man, thank you! It's been bugging me for such a long time and i was completely stumped!

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes to see the obvious ;) I would suggest you check out some form of IDE for your development. Preferably something with code highlighting AND syntax checking. Those type of editors will usually put a big red marker on the mistake helping you narrow it down.